# Distribution of median of $2n+1$ i.i.d. uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let $A_n$ be the median of $2n+1$ i.i.d. random variables which are uniform on $[0,1]$.

i) Find the probability density function of $A_n$.

ii) How does the density at $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}$ behave as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

iii) Deduce a convergence in distribution result for the median (appropriately rescaled) as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

---

I've managed to do part (i) to get $f_n(x)=\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2}x^n(1-x)^n$.

For (ii), evaluating $f(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}})$ gives $\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2}(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{a^2}{n})^n$.

Using the Stirling approximation

$f(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}})\rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{2\pi(2n+1)}((2n+1)/e)^{2n+1}}{2\pi n(n/e)^{2n}}(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{a^2}{n})^n = \frac{1}{e\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{(2n+1)^{3/2}}{n}(4+\frac{4}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})^n(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{a^2}{n})^n$.

The $(4+\frac{4}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})^n(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{a^2}{n})^n$ term approaches $e^{1-4a^2}$ so $f(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}})$ grows like $\frac{(2n+1)^{3/2}}{n}$ which grows like $\sqrt{n}$.

How should I proceed with (iii)?

Comment: (i) is a $\text{Beta}(n+1,n+1)$ distribution

Comment: check your Stirling approximation. it shouldn't be infinite. Note that you have a factor $1/4^n$ from the exponential term

Comment: @stochastic I think $f\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ has an infinite limit, but $\frac1{\sqrt n}f\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ has a finite positive limit which depends on $a$

Comment: @Henry I see. In that case, the given $f$ is not a density and should be redefined with the factor $1/\sqrt{n}$ in it.

Comment: Yes, but how would you deduce the factor of $1/\sqrt{n}$ based on the results in (ii)?

Comment: Does your use of Stirling's approximation (which has a $\sqrt{2\pi n}$ term) suggest my $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$?  Perhaps you could edit what you found into your question

Comment: You may also want to use something like $4^n (\frac{1}{4}-\frac{a^2}{n})^n \to  e^{-4a^2}$ (not checked)